# Problem importing URL with Greek characters

Tags: import, bugs, version-8, version-7, character-encoding

I'm considering buying a car. So I thought why not make a web-crawler in *Mathematica* to pile-up car data? Brilliant idea.
Then I found this Greek website, [gocar.gr](http://www.gocar.gr), which just so happens to have all the data I need in a convenient form, with URLs following a very consistent progression:

```
www.gocar.gr/cars/BRAND/MODEL/EDITION
```

e.g. `www.gocar.gr/cars/OPEL/MOKKA/1.7_CDTi_Edition_/`.

The problem is when the model or edition contains Greek letters (but not the brand? Oh wait, there *are no* Greek car brands), e.g. `www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW/ΣΕΙΡΑ_3/`, in which case `Import["URL", "Data"]` fails with a `FetchURL::conopen` error.

It seems to me that this is some kind of encoding problem (it's consistent with Greek characters appearing in the URL and everything else works).
I've seen the -kind of- relevant questions about copying non-Unicode text ([this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/copying-greek-text-from-notebooks-as-unicode) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook)), but my problem is staying **within** *Mathematica*, not copying something out of it (which, by the way, works fine).

**So, to reproduce:**

```
Import["http://www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW","Data"]
```

works, but

```
Import["http://www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW/ΣΕΙΡΑ_3","Data"]
```

doesn't.

And my question is: any ideas?

**Additional info:**

1. This is a Windows 7 / 64-bit computer; formats and location are set to Greek/Greece, Greek keyboard is installed (duh), display language is set to English, *Mathematica* version 8.
2. I also tried going directly through the JLink with a Java module I found in some other post (can't find it right now; may credit go where credit is due):

   ```
   Needs["JLink`"]

   httpGet[url_String] :=JavaBlock @
   Module[{http, get}, 
          http = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"];
          get = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod", url];
          http @ executeMethod[get]; get @ getResponseBodyAsString[]]
   ```

   followed by:

   ```
   ImportString[httpGet[URL - HERE], {"HTML", "Data"}]
   ```

   No luck.

Thank you for reading my rant.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14065/5) is probably the post you were referring to...

Comment: Well, good question -- +1. But, I don't know what to tell you besides that this was apparently a bug in version 8, since it works correctly in version 9.

Comment: I second that. Works for me Win7-64, MMA v9.01

Comment: What if you percent-encode the URLs with Greek stuff?

Comment: @rm-rf yes, thank you.

Comment: @0x4A4D percent encoding does work

Comment: @0x4A4D well, "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gocar.gr%2Fcars%2FBMW%2F%CE%A3%CE%95%CE%99%CE%A1%CE%91_3%2F" doesn't work (as expected; and it's ugly, too), but percent-encoding just e.g. "ΣΕΙΡΑ_3" in UTF8 (as in "%CE%A3%CE%95%CE%99%CE%A1%CE%91_3") does! Now that's mildly sub-optimal, but it does work. Thank you sir, you are a beautiful -unicode- character. (PS: I kind-of tried this by encoding the whole URL in ISO8859-1, which didn't work, and then I gave up. So, thank you for insisting.)

Comment: @kalt percent encoding is only meant for the path elements of the URL (and/or parameters)--not the protocol, domain name, or path separators. That's why you need to encode only the Greek text: it's not a valid URL otherwise.

Comment: @kalt You might be interested in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22680/5) by Todd Gayley (esp. the encode). So if you're building an app, all this encoding can be done in the backend and the user will never know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification [RFC1738 : "Uniform Resource Locators"](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) states that:

> The characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>      reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
>      be reserved within a scheme.
>
> [...] only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

Since the list of reserved/special characters is small, we can write an automated solution (instead of having to manually identify the Greek parts and encode like in kalt's answer) using `` ExternalService`EncodeString `` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22680/5) as:

```
encodeURL[str_String] := StringReplace[str, 
    x : Except[Alternatives @@ Characters@";/?:@=&$-_.+!*'()"] :> 
        ExternalService`EncodeString[x]]
```

(alphanumerics are handled correctly by `EncodeString`). We can now directly encode the URL:

```
encodeURL["http://www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW/ΣΕΙΡΑ_3"]
(* "http://www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW/%CE%A3%CE%95%CE%99%CE%A1%CE%91_3" *)
```

Comment: +1, but this is not correct for Unicode-based domain names. Those should be encoded using Punycode, not percent-encoding.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case somebody else needs it, here is a compiled answer.
Thanks go out to 0x4A4D (for the actual solution), Michael Pilat (for the JLink part) and everybody else in here for the swift responses.

Since this is apparently a bug of sorts in Mathematica 8, percent encoding the Greek letters in the URL will have to do.

Reciting [Michael Pilat's code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161947/2479768):

```
Needs["JLink`"]; 
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.net.URLEncoder"];

percentEncode[allGreekToMe_]:=URLEncoder`encode[allGreekToMe,"UTF-8"]
```

where 'allGreekToMe' is the Greek string.
So, the following will now work:

```
Import["http://www.gocar.gr/cars/BMW/"<>percentEncode["ΣΕΙΡΑ_3","UTF-8"],"Data"]
```

And no, I'm not buying a BMW.